# IOException:stream closed error while reading from console in java

Tags: java, ioexception

I am calling the name_setter() method from the 'main' by creating an object of customer class to get the input from console and store the name entered in the 'name' variable of the object of the customer class.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Rental {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        customer c = new customer();
        c.name_setter(); // calls the method from customer class
    }
}

class customer {
    String name;

    String name_setter() {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try {
            System.out.println("Enter the name:"); // executes till here
            name = br.readLine(); // stream close error
            System.out.println(name);
            if (name.length() == 0) {
                name = br.readLine();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("" + e);
        }

        return name;
    }
}
```

the error i am getting is:

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
```

Comment: Your code works for me, but one thing I will tell you is that you shouldn't be opening more than one stream based on System.in, and should only close it when you're completely done getting all input.

Comment: And I know that you're not doing this with the code above, but I suspect that it's part of a larger program, and that you might be opening and closing System.in based Streams and that's something you shouldn't do.

Comment: And another thing -- your program structure is broken. The class Customer (not customer, by the way -- the first letter should be upper-case), should not have user input code within it. It should have fields, such as name fields, constructor, setter and getter methods, but user input and output code should be elsewhere.

Comment: You have a method called setter, but it is not a true setter method in the JavaBean sense. Setter methods are often declared void, and should accept the data used to set the field as a parameter of the method.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels yes i have taken just an integer input using scanner class.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I am a new java programmer. Thanks for all the information. Indeed was of great help

Answer (score 1):

As Hovercraft Full Of Eels said, this code doesn't cause problem at runtime. 
It is probably different from which one rises the exception : `java.io.IOException: Stream closed`.

Beware : you chain your `BufferedReader` with the `System.in` `InputStream`.
When you close the `BufferedReader`, it closes the  `System.in`.

For example at the end of this code `System.in` is closed:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
br.close();
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

You should not close the `BufferedReader` if you want to read again in the `System.in`.
By deduction, I assume the problem comes from that.

You have the same problem with Scanner instances.

Comment: [Many many duplicates](https://www.google.com/#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+BufferedReader+System.in+stream+closed)